# How to solve the following system of linear inequalities?

Tags: inequality, linear-programming

How to solve the following system of linear inequalities in $x$, $y$ and $z$?

$$x\ge\frac{y+z}{1.9}$$
$$y\ge\frac{x+z}{2.25}$$
$$z\ge\frac{x+y}{1.6}$$
$$x,y,z\ge0$$

I'm an amateur at math.

Comment: I just tried to graph these inequalities as surfaces with computer but I don't know what is the answer.

Comment: one solution is $$x=y=z=0$$ and $$(x=0\land y=0\land z=0)\lor
   \left(x>0\land
   \left(\left(\frac{4 x}{5}\leq
   y<\frac{19 x}{18}\land
   \frac{4 y}{5}\leq z\leq
   \frac{1}{10} (19 x-10
   y)\right)\lor
   \left(y=\frac{19 x}{18}\land
   z=\frac{1}{10} (19 x-10
   y)\right)\right)\right)$$ by computer

Comment: Can you help me to do that please? @RodrigodeAzevedo

Comment: The system is homogeneous. Try the zero solution.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [the Simplex Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm). I hope you have some kind of mathematical toolbox at your disposal (excel should do it). But you basically should rewrite your problem in the form:

$$
Av=0
$$
$$
v_i \geq0 \, (\forall i)
$$

To assemble the $A$ matrix and $v$ vector :
$$
x\geq \frac{y+z}{1.9} \Rightarrow 1.9x -y-z \geq0 \Rightarrow 1.9x -y-z +t_1=0 \, (t_1 \geq0) 
$$

So the first line of $A$ is $[1.9, -1,-1,1,0,0]$. @Dr. Sonnhard Graubner already pointed a solution.